# Logistic regression results with and without odds ratio in modelsummary

Tags: r, logistic-regression, modelsummary

I like to show logistic regression with and without exponentiated coefficients side by side with the `modelsummary` package. The package produces great html output. It comes with an easy option to turn `exponentiate = TRUE` on/off. But the option applies to all models in a list.

```
log_model = glm(vs ~ am, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = mtcars)

library(modelsummary)

modelsummary(list("No Odds Ratio" = log_model), exponentiate = FALSE)
modelsummary(list("Odds Ratio" = log_model), exponentiate = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `modelsummary` function call returns a string with a "kableExtra" class representing HTML/CSS. We can add a proper div around to get what you want.

```r
log_model <- glm(vs ~ am, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mtcars)

library(modelsummary)

structure(
  paste(
    "<div style='display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;'>",
    "<div style='flex-basis: 50%;'>",
    modelsummary(list("No Odds Ratio" = log_model), exponentiate = FALSE),
    "</div>",
    "<div style='flex-basis: 50%;'>",
    modelsummary(list("Odds Ratio" = log_model), exponentiate = TRUE),
    "</div>",
    "</div>",
    collapse = "\n"
  ),
  class = "kableExtra"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Side by side tables looking great. I embed this in `bookdown`. Both tables have the same table number. Do you have any more advice on this?

Comment: Can you help me to reproduce that? What output and args for it are you using? possibly some code chunk specs are important too.

Comment: This is a powerful strategy. Nice! But see my answer for a built-in solution in `modelsummary` which requires no HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The `exponentiate` argument in `modelsummary` 1.3.0 accepts a vector of logicals to flip the switch on and off for different models. This is well-documented in `?modelsummary`. For example:

```r
library(modelsummary)
mod = glm(am ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)
mod = list("OR" = mod, "Coef" = mod)
modelsummary(mod, exponentiate = c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

|  | OR | Coef |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 0.001 | -6.604 |
|  | (0.003) | (2.351) |
| mpg | 1.359 | 0.307 |
|  | (0.156) | (0.115) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| AIC | 33.7 | 33.7 |
| BIC | 36.6 | 36.6 |
| Log.Lik. | -14.838 | -14.838 |
| F | 7.148 | 7.148 |
| RMSE | 0.39 | 0.39 |

Comment: Thanks, you added it; I assumed the op wants the same design as in the attached image. But if somebody accepts one column for parameters, then such a solution is recommended:)

Comment: This also solves the incorrect Table labels in `bookdown`. I missed the vectorization of `exponentiate`. Thanks Vincent